# Android VideoCell jar, where and what is it?

Tags: android

Anyone heard of this:

```
VideoCell cell = new VideoCell(titleStr);
```

If so where can I get the *.jar* from? And information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that, I'm guessing you read this link: [Android: Trying to get data from youtube api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023058/android-trying-to-get-data-from-youtube-api)

I came across that article and thought it had something to do with the YouTube api, but on close examination, it looks like a user defined class.

Your best bet would be to contact the guy who wrote the code and see if he's willing to give you the code for it.

Comment: I'm guessing VideoCell is a class that stores a image and text regarding the data from a video.